# Как сделать перенос строк в textEdit(PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пишу простой чат с графическим интерфейсом. Когда мне приходят сообщения я создаю отдельную переменную куда записываю помимо самого сообщения еще и "\n" (для переноса). Для того чтобы подавить экранирование я делаю: `message.replcae(r"\n", "\n")`. Потом я все это дело вывожу в textEdit без возможности изменения пользователем. По какой то причине появляется ошибка: `QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. (Parent is QTextDocument(0x21b2963d680), parent's thread is QThread(0x21b27af2a70), current thread is QThread(0x21b29af05a0)` . Буду рад помощи в ее исправлений.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Нельзя взаимодействовать в дополнительном потоке с виджетами. В Qt вы должны использовать сигналы и слоты.